# Django 'ascii' codec can't encode characters despite encoding in UTF-8? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: django, encoding, utf-8

I'm still in the process of learning Django. I have a bit of a problem with encoding a cyrillic strings. I have a text input. I append it's value using JS to the URL and then get that value in my view (I know I should probably use a form for that, but that's not the issue).

So here's my code (it's not complete, but it shows the main idea I think).

JS/HTML

```js
var notes = document.getElementById("notes").value;
...
window.location.href = 'http://my-site/example?notes='+notes
```

```html
    <input type="text" class="notes" name="notes" id="notes">
```

Django/Python

```
notes= request.GET.get('notes', 0)
try:
    notes = notes.encode('UTF-8')
except:
    pass
...
sql = 'INSERT INTO table(notes) VALUES(%s)' % str(notes)
```

The issue is, whenever I type a string in cyrillic I get this error message: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters at position... Also I know that I probably shouldn't pass strings like that to the query, but it's a personal project so... that would do for now. I've been stuck there for a while now. Any suggestions as to what's causing this would be appreciated.

Comment: did you try `encodeURIComponent` on the javascript side before calling django?

Comment: I tried it, but nothing changed. I still get the same error

Comment: But did u decode back on the view after?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I just tried that, but the same error persists...

Answer (score 0):

[`request.GET.get("key")`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#:%7E:text=the%20CONTENT_TYPE%20header.-,HttpRequest,-.GET%C2%B6) will already get a string, why you need to encode it?
May set [`request.encoding="utf-8"`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#:%7E:text=HttpRequest.-,encoding,-%C2%B6) work for you.

Comment: I'm using python2 which uses ascii as the default encoding (I assume that's what got us confused here?). That's why I'm encoding the string. I did try putting request.encoding="utf-8" as you suggested before getting the string, but that did not solve my issue.

Comment: could you print origin string after get ?